# Laravel Authentication hasValidCredentials failing

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, doctrine-orm

I am trying to setup Doctrine 2 Auth for a Laravel 5.3 app. I am using the Laravel generated Auth controllers so it's not my own custom implementation. I have made a few small changes (namely for persisting the user to the database using Doctrine) and got the registration working however when I try to login, it keeps failing authentication.

I have stepped through with a debugger and it seems to be consistently failing on the function hasValidCredentials (located at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php) as detailed below:

```
  /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        if (strlen($hashedValue) === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
    }
```

For reference, my values for $value and $hashedValue are as follows:

> $value = "tester";
>   $hashedValue = "$2y$10$ZSLRE3LAVA8myaH8mu6TNeumQxHdmKRbv/zZdFQeDujZ8JolshTOu";

A screenshot of the Variables as per my last XDebug session shows the exact type of the variables:

[image: credential values]

The $hashedValue is the encrypted version (using bcrypt) of the password "tester" so I know the credentials are 100% correct however when execution hits password_verify, it always evaluates to false and then the hasValidCredentials check fails.

I am storing my user as follows in my database:
[image: user table setup]

So I know that the hashed password is long enough and being stored in the database. I see that $hashedValue is returned in double quotes, could this be a problem?

Regardless I cannot login as the attempt function of the Session Guard class always fails as hasValidCredentials always returns false and I am quite stumped as the credentials are accurate.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the following evaluates to true:

`password_verify('secret password', '$2y$10$EnIi90KP.0BqCVJgK21BrO3xzArxCZaiAPaUebCw.K2Xw71QOCZv2');`

Comment: Do note that my app key is in base64 encoded. Could that also cause issues when generating the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) is a native php function, basically the counterpart of [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). since

```
password_verify('tester', '$2y$10$ZSLRE3LAVA8myaH8mu6TNeumQxHdmKRbv/zZdFQeDujZ8JolshTOu');
```

returns `false`, your `$hashedValue` is **not** the encrypted value of `tester`.

My guess would be that you somehow double encrypted your password, e.g. your laravel component and your doctrine component are both hashing the password value.

Note that laravel's `app.key` is not used for encrypting the passwords, as you can see in the [BcryptHasher](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php), therefore it can't affect the result.

Comment: Thanks passioncoder. I was running bcrypt on it after Laravel had already run Hash::make on the input.